# How to set retention policy of logs in Secor?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka

I am using pinterest Secor to fetch logs from Kakfa and uploading to S3. While everything else is working fine, the logs fetched by Secor are not getting deleted and thus filling the disk.
 
I have searched through all the properties but couldn't find any log retention policy in any files.

How to set the retention policy in Secor?
 Any help/pointers are deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting log4j property value as

```
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

which should retain 10 latest log files

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to solve this can be - to have a crontab running in your machine, that keeps deleting the old log files.